# Can't delete file from trash as root

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, bleachbit

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and deleted a file as root to trash.
Then I couldn't delete it because root nautilus won't view trash, and I installed bleachbit and used it as root but it won't clean it either.

Comment: Generally you don't want to open a file explorer as root. You can do this from a terminal `sudo rm -rf /home/$username/.local/share/Trash/`

Answer (score 12):

To delete a file as `root` you need to open nautilus as root by typing in terminal

```
sudo -H nautilus
```

Then inside nautilus use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to show the hidden files. After that navigate to `/home/username/.local/share/Trash/files`.

And delete the files easily.